# FFmpeg make video from figures and speed up a chosen part

Tags: ffmpeg

Make a video from a series of 100 figures

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i input_figure%01d.png out.mp4
```

How can I only make figure numbers from [0-49] with a slower speed like `-framerate 5`?

My try is

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 5 -i input_figure%01d.png -vframes 49 \
-start_number 50 -framerate 10 -i input_figure%01d.png \
out.mp4
```

Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The naive method is to create videos in parts, then concat them togother

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i input_fig%01d.png -vframes 49 part_1.mp4

ffmpeg -start_number 50 -framerate 10 -i input_fig%01d.png part_2.mp4

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0\
    -i <(for f in ./part_*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done)\
    -c copy out.mp4

rm part_*.mp4
```